# SQL SQlite3 (Operational Error?)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Getting an operation error with this line. Any idea of whats wrong with the SQL statement? (Bit of a sql noob)
Basically just want a way to get an item from a table in where a corresponding item to that record is equal to either of the two options. Code below, thanks!

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT test_id FROM test WHERE class_id = ? OR 
WHERE class_id = ?",(self.classIDs[0],self.classIDs[1]))
```

Comment: try to remove the second `WHERE` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query has two WHERE clauses.  You could do `where class_id IN (?, ?)`.